# Chrome mDNS api producing empty device list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, mdns

I have the following code that should be fetching a list of multicast devices in the background script of a packaged chrome app

```
const onDevices = (devices) => {
    console.log(devices);
}

const serviceType = '_http._tcp';

chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    outerBounds: {
        width: 400,
        height: 500
    }
});


chrome.mdns.onServiceList.addListener(onDevices, {serviceType});

chrome.mdns.forceDiscovery(() => {
    console.log('start');
})
```

but when I run `console.log(devices)` I always end up with an empty list. This happens no matter what I set `serviceType` to.

I'm using manifest version 2 if that matters.

I know there are multicast devices on the network, so any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: See [valid service type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-discovery-api-20140220/#dfn-valid-service-type) definition.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see how the W3C spec is relevant to a chrome API. Furthermore that spec appears to be outdated

Comment: Eh????? The w3c spec is linked in `chrome.mdns` documentation - apparently because it's the origin/base for the Chrome's API. Yes, it's deprecated in the web, but this fact is irrelevant since chrome apps/extension API is not regulated by w3c.